# Html Agility Pack help

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape some information from a website but can't find a solution that works for me. Every code I read on the Internet generates at least one error for me.

Even the example code at their homepage generates errors for me.

My code:

```
         HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
         doc.Load("https://www.flashback.org/u479804");
         foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
         {
            HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
            att.Value = FixLink(att);
         }
         doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Generates the following error:

'HtmlDocument' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' and 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument' C:*\Form1.cs

**Edit: My entire code is located here: http://beta.yapaste.com/55**

All help is very appreciated!

Comment: As I mentioned in my reply below I can't really tell what you are trying to do. If you can describe the task you are trying to achieve in some more detail I will try to help you write a sample app to achieve it.

Comment: I reckon you could use "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument" instead of "HtmlDocument" to shut the compiler up.

Comment: Ah, it was the "using HtmlDocument = System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument;" that somehow "magically" got added to my usings clause, which was obscuring the HtmlAgilityPack version of the HtmlDocument class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

The compiler is getting confused because two of the namespaces you have imported with `using` contain classes called `HtmlDocument` - the HTML Agility Pack namespace, and the Windows Forms namespace. You can get around this by specifying which class you want to use explicitly.

Comment: Then I get another error:
    'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'DocumentElement' and no extension method 'DocumentElement' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Victor: I'm not really sure of the exact layout of the library, but I do see the example code http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home. From the comment right at the bottom of that page, you might want to try `DocumentNode` instead of `DocumentElement`. It's a bit of a long-shot though...

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure then. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you've pasted in... maybe there is an error elsewhere?

Comment: Is there any alternative way I could grab information from a website using C#?

Comment: The library you're using is the best way I know to do what you want to do... you could try creating a new project, and doing only the minimum necessary to get the sample code working. Or, if it includes a full sample app, looking to see if there are any differences between your code and its.

Answer (score 4):

this is how i achieved. Note that there is a code error given in main [Html Agility Pack Example](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) in foreach line doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"]). The correct and tested one is given below.

```
 HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();

    HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(@"http://adityabajaj.com");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    List<string> lstHref = new List<string>();

    foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Distinct())
    {
        string curHref = link.Attributes["href"].Value;

        if(!lstHref.Contains(curHref))
        lstHref.Add(curHref);

    }
    foreach (string str in lstHref)
    {
        sb.Append(str +"<br />");
    }

    Response.Write (sb.ToString());
```

Since it got working for me, I thought I should share.

Answer (score 2):

The classes in the two namespaces `System.Windows.Forms` and `HtmlAgilityPack` are conflicting. Use fully-qualified type names or use namespace aliases.

Comment: That did not help me too much, could you evolve what I should do a little more?

Answer (score 1):

I have written a couple of articles that explain how to use HtmlAgilityPack. You might find them useful to get started:

- http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/search/label/HtmlAgilityPack

***WARNING (2012-06-08): This link is a bit spammy - dodgy pop-under adverts, not much content.***

I don't know if they have fixed it now but that snippet didn't used to work on the homepage of the site, I think it was from an earlier version of the library. Also the snippet doesn't define FixLink() so it wouldn't work even if it was correct for the library.

I would recommend getting the latest beta version of the library because it has extra extensions for performing linq queries against it which can save you from confusing xpath queries later on.

I haven't seen it used in a Windows Forms app before but it looks like you will have to use fully-qualified type names like:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

As for the actual task you are trying to perform, it seems like you want to take a url, inject a username and id into it and then... not sure? You look like you are both trying to save the file out to disk and set the html code to the contents of a Form which I don't think you can do?

Comment: @tomfanning - thanks for the notification, it seems one of the widgets was spamming users. I have removed PostRank and Blogged.com widgets and I'm not seeing the spam pop unders anymore.