# How do i use htmlagilitypack DocumentElement not exist?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, html-agility-pack

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(htmlCode);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{

}
```

I am getting an error that `DocumentElement` is not exist:

> Error  1   'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'DocumentElement' and no extension method 'DocumentElement' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a code sample from the [examples](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) page of the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

This code sample is not working, you should try the following code instead (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14548374/4840746))

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(htmlCode);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{

}
```